# Export curved text labels and lines to SVG in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, export, svg

I try to export a map to SVG in QGIS. The print composer looks like this:
[image]

when I open the exported SVG in Illustrator it looks like this:
[image]

Now I have 2 problems.

- 1. The geometries obiously look very strange and I can't figure out why.
     [SVG from QGIS to Illustrator CC gets wrong stroke widths](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123666/svg-from-qgis-to-illustrator-cc-gets-wrong-stroke-widths?rq=1) (kind of a solution)
- 2. The exported labels are NOT text objects. Within the
     placement-properties of the labels I checked "curved". Without the
     "curved" I get text objects, but that does not help me. I need those 
     labels curved. Are curved labels AND text objects even possible?

I have read a lot of QGIS / SVG questions and it seems that the SVG export of QGIS is a pure mess. Is this the case or am I doing something wrong? (Exporting lines and labels can't be so hard.)

Comment: There is limitation in the way that SVG is exported, you have to do some post processing in Illustrator/Inkscape to improve the export. in Abobe Illustrator you can set up actions that happen if you have many files to process.

Comment: well, when the labels are not text objects (every letter is one single object), than it is almost impossible to do some good post processing. i'm open for any suggestions. as is said, the svg export of non-curved labels works fine.

Comment: I tracked it down use the 'Join Text Frames Script' http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/joinTextFrames.js you can customize this more to preserve your text more.